# Does modifications is needed for Java web application code if we want to upgrade the OS and DB version?

Tags: java, struts

we have two java web application. Java versions for both applications are 1.5. It is using oracle DB(v11.2.0.3) and running in Red hat(Version 7) . Now we are looking to upgrade the OS to red hat 8 and DB to v19. Does my application needs to be modified in order to be compatible with OS, DB upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to upgrade your OJDBC library to interface with the new version of Oracle, but likely no more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the library, I will say test JDBC connection properties.